# Successfully Hosted Nodejs app on render not responding

Tags: node.js, render, web-deployment

I have a nodejs app which uses handlebars as templating engine, the app run perfectly fine with no errors on development, and also after hosting it on render the renter's console show status for successful deployment and it's live right now. But the problem is that when ever I make request the site it never respond.
[The GitHub repo](https://github.com/armanvirus/Big-tailor)

While the hosted site's link is [here](https://arkexpress.onrender.com)

Render's event logs
[image]

Comment: repo is not public. Either make it public or share relevant code here

Comment: Your serverlog shows shomething like "*the server is working on 10000*" I suppose that's the port the server is listening to? Never used `onrender` before, but are you sure, you somehow connected this serverport to the public port 443, which is used by default when you browse to `https://example.onrender.com`?

Comment: BTW Better would be posting the serverlogs as text and not as image. Currently they are barely readable ...

Comment: No I just let the render to assign port on it self by setting the port variable as, process.env.PORT || 300, then the render assign's 10000 to be the port number